# Delta Method Confidence Intervals

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, delta-method

In a standard linear regression setup:  $$ y_t = \beta X + \varepsilon _t$$ where

$$ e_t \sim N(0, \sigma ^{2}) $$

I have found the Maximum Likelihood Estimators for β and σ (from OLS), but now want to compute a 95% confidence interval for β/σ. From initial research it seems that I can use the delta method for this calculation, but am not sure how to do so. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

Under regularity conditions, the MLE is asymptotically normal. Specifically,

$$ \sqrt{t}\left(\begin{pmatrix}{\hat{\beta}\\
\hat{\sigma}^2}\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}{\beta\\
\sigma^2}\end{pmatrix}\right) \xrightarrow{D} N\left(0,I^{-1}(\beta,\sigma^2)\right) $$

where $I^{-1}(\beta,\sigma^2)$ represents the inverse Fisher information matrix. Now, you can apply the [bivariate delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Multivariate_delta_method) using the function, $g(x,y) = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{y}}$. Essentially the limiting distribution will also be normal allowing you to construct a large sample confidence interval for $g(\beta, \sigma^2) = \dfrac{\beta}{\sigma}$ this way.

Comment: Plus a lot of software (e.g. PROC NLMIXED in SAS) would do this for you automatically.

Comment: As a bonus hint, the information matrix is diagonal (independent coefficient/residual variance) when homoscedasticity is met.